# Python Invalid Syntax IF statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, syntax-error

I'm trying to make a quiz in python but I keep getting invalid syntax errors.

```
#This is for addition questions.

if (question=add)  <---- That is where i get the error
for i in range(0,10):
    first_number_add=random.randint(1,50)
    second_number_add=random.randint(1,50)
    answer=int(input(str(first_number_add) + '+' + str(second_number_add) + '='))
    sum=first_number_add+second_number_add
    if (answer==sum):
        print ('Correct')
        stats['correct'] += 1
    else:
        print ('Incorrect.')
        stats['incorrect'] += 1
```

Comment: The "<---- That's where i get the error" is not in the actual code

Comment: you've missed the colon out.

Comment: `if (question=add)` Use `==` instead and add `:`.

Comment: Where do I add the colon ....

Answer (score 4):

for comparasion you need to use `==`:

```
if question==add:   #you dont need bracket here
    # do your stuff
```

`sum` is built-in sum function dont use it for variable name

Answer (score 1):

Replace with `if question == add:` and indent the rest of your code.

Also, don't use `sum` as variable name. It is a useful function.

```
if question == add:
    for i in range(10):
        first_number_add = random.randint(1,50)
        second_number_add = random.randint(1,50)
        answer = int(input(str(first_number_add) + '+' + str(second_number_add) + '='))
        the_sum = first_number_add + second_number_add
        if answer == the_sum:
            print('Correct')
            stats['correct'] += 1
        else:
            print('Incorrect.')
            stats['incorrect'] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if question==add:  
    for i in range(0,10):
        first_number_add=random.randint(1,50)
        second_number_add=random.randint(1,50)
        answer=int(input(str(first_number_add) + '+' + str(second_number_add) + '='))
        sum=first_number_add+second_number_add
        if answer==sum:
            print ('Correct')
            stats['correct'] += 1
        else:
            print ('Incorrect.')
            stats['incorrect'] += 1
```

You don't need parantheses. Also you have to put 4 spaces in indent after for loop and if statement. As @Joel comment, 4 spaces is standard, you can change it to 8-16 etc.

Comment: note for OP: technically the indenting doesn't need to be 4 spaces (but it does need to be a consistent amount).  4 spaces is the standard, so you should stick to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if question==add:  
    for i in range(0,10):
        first_number_add=random.randint(1,50)
        second_number_add=random.randint(1,50)
        answer=int(input(str(first_number_add) + '+' + str(second_number_add) + '='))
        sum=first_number_add+second_number_add
        if answer==sum:
            print ('Correct')
            stats['correct'] += 1
        else:
            print ('Incorrect.')
            stats['incorrect'] += 1
```

No need of parenthesis in python... and please keep in mind to provide a consistent indentation(same number of spaces) with every block and looping statement.